# Update with Parameters Command in C# is not working

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

Good day.

This is my update parameters code:

=================================================================================

```
UpdateCmd.CommandTimeout = 200;
UpdateCmd.Parameters.Add("@Status", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "Status");
UpdateCmd.Parameters.Add("@JONumber", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "JONumber");
UpdateCmd.Parameters["@Status"].Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM d yyyy h:mm:ss tt") + " " + "Acknowledged";
UpdateCmd.Parameters["@JONumber"].Value = "7796";
UpdateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

==================================================================================

Now this is the full code:

```
string updateSql = "UPDATE dbo.Table4 SET Status = Status + ', ' @Status + Name" + "WHERE JONumber = @JONumber";            
myConnection = new SqlConnection("server=192.168.249.4, 1433;" + "user id=SQL User;" +
                                "password=8C=S&6dw{2;" +
                                "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                                "database=ADMIN; " +
                                "connection timeout=200");
try
{
myConnection.Open();
ConsoleWriteLine("Database Open...");
SqlCommand UpdateCmd = new SqlCommand(updateSql, myConnection);
Update.CommandTimeout = 200;
UpdateCmd.CommandTimeout = 200;
UpdateCmd.Parameters.Add("@Status", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "Status");
UpdateCmd.Parameters.Add("@JONumber", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "JONumber");
UpdateCmd.Parameters["@Status"].Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM d yyyy h:mm:ss tt") + " " + "Acknowledged";
UpdateCmd.Parameters["@JONumber"].Value = "7796";
UpdateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
ConsoleWriteLine("Testing Successful!!");
UpdateCmd.Dispose();
myConnection.Close();
}
catch (Exception err)
{
ConsoleWriteLine("Error: " + err.ToString());
}
if (myConnection != null)
{
myConnection.Close();
}
```

================================================================================
Note:
1) Connection is established IF the following code is DELETED from it:

```
    UpdateCmd.CommandTimeout = 200;
UpdateCmd.Parameters.Add("@Status", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "Status");
UpdateCmd.Parameters.Add("@JONumber", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "JONumber");
UpdateCmd.Parameters["@Status"].Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM d yyyy h:mm:ss tt") + " " +   "Acknowledged";
UpdateCmd.Parameters["@JONumber"].Value = "7796";
UpdateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

2) If the above code is not deleted the following error is displayed:

```
Error: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near '@Status'. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()at GSMTechnicalReportWebService.MainWindow.button3_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
ClientConnectionId:f291cc22-e926-42ad-9901-9f44d088bd0d
```

3) I also tried this method but same error:

```
try
{
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("user id=SQL User;" + "password=8C=S&6dw{2;server=192.168.249.4, 1433;" + "Trusted_Connection=yes;" + "database=ADMIN; " + "connection timeout=200"))
{
conn.Open();
string updateSql = "UPDATE dbo.Table4 SET Status = Status + ', ' @Status + Name" + "WHERE JONumber = @JONumber";
using (SqlCommand UpdateCmd = new SqlCommand(updateSql, conn))
{
UpdateCmd.CommandTimeout = 200;
UpdateCmd.Parameters.Add("@Status", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "Status");
                    UpdateCmd.Parameters.Add("@JONumber", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "JONumber");
                    UpdateCmd.Parameters["@Status"].Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM d yyyy h:mm:ss tt") + " " + "Acknowledged";
                    UpdateCmd.Parameters["@JONumber"].Value = "7796";
                    UpdateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    UpdateCmd.Dispose();
                    myConnection.Close();
                }
                conn.Close();

            }

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            ConsoleWriteLine("Error: " + e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

4) Database is Microsoft SQL Server

=============================================================================

Now: My question are:

1) Is my code is correct? If yes, Did i miss anything? If no, can you verify it for me?

2) What is the proper way to updated database in microsoft sql server using c#?

3) Are there any methods so that my database can be updated?

Comment: You're missing a + in the line `SET Status = Status + ', ' @Status`

Comment: in which part? as i double checked it, it is there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this line is the problem

```
string updateSql = "UPDATE dbo.Table4 SET Status = Status + ', ' @Status + Name" + "WHERE JONumber = @JONumber";
```

The above code would generate the following SQL syntax

```
UPDATE dbo.Table4 SET Status = Status + ', ' @Status + NameWHERE JONumber = @JONumber
```

which is invalid because there's no `+` before `@Status` and there's no space between `Name` and `WHERE`, hence you got the `Incorrect syntax near '@Status'` error.

Try to change it to below

```
string updateSql = "UPDATE dbo.Table4 SET Status = Status + ', ' + @Status + Name WHERE JONumber = @JONumber";
```

Comment: done that but still the same error

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Do you want to update just the `Status` column with the value of `@Status`?